How the balance of nature prevents the creation of superpowers?
We all intuitively know that when nature gives, it also takes, in order to maintain the balance. Without this careful orchestration, billions of years of evolution would already produce a dominant superbug or a super animal or a superhuman. And we would definitely know about it because natural selection would quickly achieve dominance of this super**** entity in the world.
So how does a natural (unassisted) process put the breaks in super-creation?

@andrós - There were trade-offs, as usual. Humans did get a big brain, but they lost muscle power (10 times weaker than chimps), acquired a weak immune system (they cannot survive in the wild).

The things that made all the Oxygen in the atmosphere had dominance a couple billion years ago, poisoning most everything else and then themselves, until something found a use for all that free oxygen.

@ScottRowe - Dinosaurs also developed a significant dominance, until asteroid came.

Well, if we ever see any life beyond earth, we'll get some interesting new data points. Planet sized organisms, life seeding spiral arms, self-organizing light, whatever.

@ScottRowe - Strange! I just thought about Solaris. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvm7WMbXfeY

When a predator is too efficient it depletes it's prey's population, which reduces its available food and in the end leads to it's own population collapse. Or it makes place for another type of prey who is better suited to avoid the predator and strives, as a result making said predator not so super. Evolution is not about grading species on a single axis, it's about being efficient in a given environment. Whatever is maximally efficient in a given situation becomes innadapted when circumstances change. There is nothing mystical or purposeful behind it.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance "they lost muscle power (10 times weaker than chimps)" - this is an urban legend. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5514706/ Pound for pound, chimpanzee muscle can only exert 1.35x-1.5x what a human can, not 10x, and this is just because human muscle has more slow-twitch fibers for endurance in repetitive activities while chimps have more fast-twitch fibers for short bursts of strength (and thus, less endurance).

@ScottRowe, "life seeding spiral arms (of spiral galaxies)"?

This is classic feedback-control systems.
Note: The terminology is a bit misleading because “positive feedback” has the negative behavior of crashing the system.
Any system that adjusts from external data + internal “memory” must have negative feedback loops if it is to remain stable. See why negative feedback is also called balancing feedback.
A classic example of a positive feedback breaking the system is the deafening whine/roar that happens in a PA system when the speaker “feeds back” into the microphone.
A more elaborate example closer to what you are asking is how sexual reproduction pans out in social species, particularly homo sapiens.
Man and woman feel attracted to one another.
What they internally represent as “love” is the selfish gene driving reproduction. This the positive feedback.
But the family of the man and the woman — archetypally the in-laws — don't experience the same love, what they represent as “family-quarrels”, social-pressures. This the negative feedback.
If there were not the latter, the man-woman pair would get 'stuck' like the microphone-speaker and produce infinite babies!
So from negative+positive working together in concert you get the makeup of social units that cohere, at least relatively speaking.
In like manner if the eco-unit must cohere relatively speaking (here 'cohere' means relatively infinite lifetime compared to the individual units) one species cannot completely dominate the rest without control loops kicking in.
Contrary to Andros comment, I dont regard homo sapiens as "superior" but rather as a parasite or a cancer that is killing the host — Consider global warming, nuclear winter etc etc. at their pessimistic worst.

"selfish gene driving reproduction" - Only a really young person could think that way. Love is a reward. Love cannot be explained by some physical or sexual reasons. Love is a gift. Usually, it means that you fulfilled your purpose pretty well, if you know what love is.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance If the loving person knew that he/she would not be young!! The reason reproduction works so well is that each reproducing pair thinks I am Prince Charming; Sleeping Beauty. Once the reproduction cycle is complete, nature discards the parents or at least relegates them to a secondary role of caretakers. Then in your old age when the eyes open you say Oh! I was just one of 4 billion mating pairs

I like this expression: "Children come and go, but your wife stays". Usually, sex has very little to do with love.

I find Gurdjieff deeper: Wife can be many; mother is only one. Captures in an inexorable way what it means that beyond all the shenanigans we are just mammals. [Mammae: Source of mother's milk]

Your belief in a magical “balance” is an inappropriate extrapolation and misidentification of what is actually happening.  Balance is only the byproduct of species interacting with the consequence of ecosystem constraints.  A species that becomes too “super” will overwhelm species in nearby niches, crashing its ecosystem, and reducing the supportable biomass. Such species do not thrive because of the biomass feedback loop.
Humans are approaching such a biomass collapse.  Between us and our dependent animals, we have displaced over 85% of the biomass of mammals in the world. This is almost certainly beyond a sustainable  level of ecosystems.  When ecosystem collapses will happen and what they will look like we don’t know yet.  But they are in our future because we are being too “super”.

Oh! I did not notice that we wrote the same answer. Heh.

One example would be Rabbits in Australia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbits_in_Australia

"magical" balance. . Have you heard of The Gaia Hypothesis? Not many takers, but reportedly unfalsified. Very little supporting evidence except for the earth's apparent stability.

@ThomasW, interesting article. We should have taken heed of Fibonacci!!

@Hudjefa Yes I am aware of the Gaia hypothesis.   The response rate of simpler species to collapsed ecosystems is for bacteria, fungii, etc to make use of that now unused carbon, so Gaia does not lose biomass, only complexity,  Gaia cannot sustain loss of too much complexity with out a degradation of the feedback loop within its remaining ecosystems.  The hypothesis in a mitigated form fully matches the feedback loop concept.  Deep Ecology references Gaia, but notes Gaia is not rational, nor plans, and holds that we humans must serve as Gaia's rational and planning arm.

@Decleve, mirabilis audire. Is the lack of progress in TGH (it's the scientific version of a Wiki stub) a case of skepticism or one of hard problem? I get why TGH needs to distance itself from religion, hence the caveats that there is no plan that's being executed.
